# could not broadcast input array from shape (150,150,3) into shape (150,150,3,3)

Tags: arrays, tensorflow, input, model

I tried to train the model

```
EPOCHS = 5
history = model.fit(train_data, steps_per_epoch=len(train_generator), epochs=EPOCHS, validation_data=val_data, validation_steps=len(val_generator))
```

but I get this error:

> Value error : could not broadcast input array from shape (150,150,3)
> into shape (150,150,3,3).

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

The broadcasting will be possible if you change the input of shape (150,150,3) to (150,150,3,1) . for example in tensorflow :

```
`input = tf.expand_dims(input , -1)`
```